# Image Zooming Feature using jQuery CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created script which dynamically change the product image on click event but i need to add zooming feature on Big Image when mouse move on big Image.

HTML code

```
<ul class="thumbelina" style="top: -220px;">
    <li style="display: block;">
         <img class="showBigImage" src="/Chrysanthemum-69x52.jpg" data-fullurl="/Chrysanthemum.jpg">
   </li>
   <li style="display: block;">
         <img class="showBigImage" src="/Lighthouse-69x52.jpg" data-fullurl="/Lighthouse.jpg">
   </li>
   <li style="display: block;">
         <img class="showBigImage" src="/Penguins-69x52.jpg" data-fullurl="/Penguins.jpg">
   </li>
</ul>
<div>
  <img class="bigImage" src="/Penguins.jpg" />
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(".showBigImage").click(function(){
    var FullImageUrl = $(this).data("fullurl");
    $(".bigImage").attr("src", FullImageUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onfocus -> animate to new height and width,

is this what you want to reach? i could not give a better answer because the question was a little unclear to me. if you want a better answer please expand your question for me

Comment: I need zoomin feature like http://www.starplugins.com/thumbelina when you mouse over on large image you can see the effect i need to do using custom CSS and jQuery.

Comment: im looking for for you but this is an plugin .. you could peek into code and use some of the ideas. but make sure if you copy you add credits to original